# multiple custom sub domains on Nodejitsu?

Tags: nodejitsu

I have 2 apps hosted on Nodejitsu

**1st app** ('main' site)..package.json:-

```
"subdomain": "myapp",
"domains": [
  "myapp.com",
  "www.myapp.com"
],
```

this serves successfully out of **www.myapp.com** and **myapp.com**

2nd app..package.json:-

```
"subdomain": "myaccount.myapp-otherapp",
"domains": [
  "otherapp.myapp.com"
],
```

I want this second app to serve out of **otherapp.myapp.com**, the app page on Nodejitsu lists both **otherapp.myapp.com** and **myaccount.myapp-otherappp.jit.su** as 'domains' but only the jit.su domain actually works, the other one just hangs/times out.

Any clues?

Comment: note that the 'subdomain' setting is purely related to the nodejitsu account, all custom domain stuff should be done in the 'domains' setting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I hadn't added a CNAME record for the subdomain.  I added one (otherapp.myapp.com.. mapping to nodejitsu and it worked fine.

Comment: Perfect! I had the same exact issue : )